# CSS: How to make a background-image appear within a div without setting a fixed height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have made the following layout:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/120/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-12 header"></div>
</div>
```

It works because I have used a height-property with a fixed pixel-value.

If one removes that the image disappears:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/120/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-12 header"></div>
</div>
```

One of the problems with using that fixed height is that responsiveness can't be accomplished.

**How can I make the background appear without having to use a fixed height?
Or should I fall back to using img-tag instead?**

There the height is determined by the image-sizes itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewport height` to make div responsive, in below example `40vh` is 40% of viewport height.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/120/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-12 header"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your `.header` doesn't have any content, and thus its height is actually 0px....

To change that, you can either put content into your `.header` like: text, images... OR give it height via css, either static (in px), or dynamic (via '%', or 'vh'...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one transparent image like below:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/120/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.header img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-12 header">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAGQBAMAAACkCxkHAAAAGFBMVEUAAAD///+TlJWcnp+Ji4yIiouVlZaSk5OelJf9AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAANVJREFUeF7tzTEVgEAMBbB/HZivDhCBBAQgBf8TLngdEgNJZw6qszMGV1YG4X6OHxYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA3g1DZGYSVPjMG1R9lOgHLp7M9BAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can change window size here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gcejf26t/

If you noticed images are showed weird, because they are just like that! nothing to do with CSS (of course transparent image ratio can be equal to your image's ratio).

You can find smaller base64 coded image in comparison with that I've used and also better ratio as you desire.

But why you should do this? I don't know! Use `<img>` for simplicity.